# Get as many nested Records in returnType as the arguments passed to the function

Tags: typescript, function, typescript-typings, return-type, nested-object

What I am trying to achieve is typing a deeply nested ReturnType of a function, based on the number of arguments provided in the "rest" argument. For example, if we have:

```
getFormattedDates(
  dates: Date[],
  ...rest: string[] // ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', etc...]
): Record<string, Record<string, Record<string,etc...>>>
```

The last nested object should be of type `Record<string, Date[]>`, while if there is no 2nd argument, the return type should be `Date[]`.

So far I have tried googling various things, but I couldn't get a hold on such a type, and I would also like to understand the logic behind it.

This is my first question ever asked, so I hope it is explicit enough. :)

Hope someone can shed some light on this issue. Thanks!

Comment: You could achieve this with conditional and recursive types

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do *quite* what you asked. If you look at the types for similar platform functions (`Object.assign`, for instance), they're defined as a series of function overloads out to ten (IIRC) arguments that are fairly smart about the return value, and then a catch-all for more than ten that's not as smart. You could do something similar, with a single argument overload returning `Record<string, Date[]>`, the two argument returning `Record<string, Record<string, Date[]>>`, etc. Your > 10 would probably be a recursive type without known bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the type [recursively](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types):

```
type ToRecord<T> = T extends [string, ...infer Rest]
    ? Record<string, ToRecord<Rest>>
    : Date[]

declare function getFormattedDates<T extends string[]>(
    dates: Date[],
    ...rest: T // ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', etc...]
): ToRecord<T>

const p0 = getFormattedDates([]) // Date[]
const p1 = getFormattedDates([], 'AAA') // Record<string, Date[]>
const p3 = getFormattedDates([], 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC') // Record<string, Record<string, Record<string, Date[]>>>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-AAcnA3Ckb6JChGAoABkGIbcOwcDNsAap1oWFgODQ0AZmglbINGGSFHkJyoWe6FghatRAA)

Comment: This seems to be the right way to go. I have to explore and understand the concept, but there is one thing, which is that if there is only 'AAA' in the 2nd argument, then the returnType would be Record<string, Date[]>, while if there is no 2nd argument, the return type is Date[].

I think I gave the wrong example above by adding an additional Record. If anything, based on your example I'll try to figure it out! Super thanks!

Comment: @Razvan updated the answer, let me know if you have any questions 

Comment: I would be curious to know how would you read the `ToRecord` type as pseudocode, besides the generic T?

Comment: @Razvan I've updated the playground with some explanations, hope that helps.